# Refer to the current directory with <base> set

Tags: html, directory, href, radix

Setting `<base href="/a/">` causes `<a href="/b">` to resolve to `/a/b`. This is fine.

However, if I have an HTML file `/a/b/x.html` and I want to refer to `/a/b/y.html`, it would seem the only way to do this is `<a href="/b/y.html">`.

Normally (without setting `<base>`), I can refer to a file in the current directory with `./y.html` or even just `y.html`. But with `<base>` set, the `./` does not resolve to the current directory, it resolves to the directory specified in `<base>`.

**A more complex example:**

```
a
└─b
  └─c
    └─d     
      |──x.html
      └──y.html
```

If I am in `x.html` and `base` is set to `/a/`, how can I refer to `y.html` without writing everything between `b` and `d`? Is there a way to refer to the current directory, ignoring the `base` tag?

Answer (score 0):

of course, but not without some javascript hack :)

on `x.html`, add

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.location.replace(document.location.href.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')+'/y.html');">Go to Y</a>
```